# delay function execution JS

Tags: javascript

I want to toggle between showing and hiding two divs on a `mouseenter` and `click` event. However, if the click event happens in the same position as the mouseenter area the functions go into a loop, illustrated in the gif below.

[image]

How can I delay the `showOverlay` function for a few seconds but maintain the `mouseenter` event working normally like in the gif below (i.e no delay):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

```js
var hover = document.querySelector('#hover');
var overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');
var primary = document.querySelector('#primary');
var overlayShowing = false;
var clicked = false

function showOverlay() {
  overlayShowing = true
    overlay.classList.add('display');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      overlay.classList.add('active');
    }, 100);
    primary.classList.add('nactive');
}

function hideOverlay() {
  overlayShowing = false
  overlay.classList.remove('active');

  primary.classList.remove('hidden');
  setTimeout(function(){
    primary.classList.remove('nactive');
  }, 100); 
}

primary.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  if(overlayShowing) {
     primary.classList.add('hidden');
   }
 })

overlay.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  if(!overlayShowing) {
  overlay.classList.remove('display');
  }
  
});

hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
  showOverlay();
});

overlay.addEventListener("click", function() {
  hideOverlay();
});
```

```css
#primary {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s ease
}
#primary.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
#primary.nactive {
  opacity: 0;
}
#hover {
  font-size: 150px;
}
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease
}
#overlay.active {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#overlay.display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary">
  <div id="hover">HOVER</div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Hint: `clearTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a timeout to delay the showing:

```
  var showTimeout;

  function showOverlay() {
   if(showTimeout) return;

   showTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
     overlayShowing = true;
     overlay.classList.add('display');
     setTimeout(function(){ 
       overlay.classList.add('active');
      }, 100);
      primary.classList.add('nactive');
  }, 500);
 }

 function hideOverlay() {
   if(showTimeout) {
     clearTimeout(showTimeout);
     showTimeout = null;
   }

   overlayShowing = false
   overlay.classList.remove('active');

   primary.classList.remove('hidden');
   setTimeout(function(){
     primary.classList.remove('nactive');
   }, 100); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate the help. I attempted a similar approach (less elegantly) but the problem I encountered and the same problem with this solution is that the delay should only happen if the mouse is still over the `#hover` element after the `click` event. There should be no delay if it is just a normal `mouseenter`, this is what I tried to illustrate in the second gif.